# as3 text field to enter a certain number of characters

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, character

There are one array and textfiled type input

```
myarray=["h","e","l","l","o"];
```

I need to only one "h","e","o" and two times "l" keypress input to textfield

This is it possible?

Comment: are you trying to validate something?

Comment: I have no idea what your talking about

Comment: Yes, but until the input array elements and characters
example 1 times "h", 1 times "e", 2 times "l", 1 times "o",
not another enter characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and found. Thanks for another answers

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var tf:TextField = new TextField  ;
tf.border = true;
tf.type = "input";
addChild(tf);
tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,reportKeyDown);
var dizi:Array = "hello".split("");
var yazilan:Array=new Array();
function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
   {
       tf.restrict = dizi.toString();
       var harfsira:int;
       harfsira = dizi.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
       trace(harfsira);
       trace("character: " + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) +         " (key code: " + event.keyCode + " character code: "         + event.charCode + ")");
           if (harfsira >-1)
               {
                  yazilan.push(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
                  dizi.splice((harfsira),1);
                  trace(yazilan.toString()+" "+"input character");
                  trace(dizi.toString()+" "+"restrict characters");
              }
              else
              {
                  trace("end of restrict character");
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't care about the order :

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    var myarray:Array = ["h","e","l","l","o"];

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
        tf.border = true;
        tf.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);
        addChild(tf);

    }

    private function onInput(e:TextEvent):void 
    {
        var index:int = myarray.indexOf(e.text);
        if (index == -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            myarray.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

}
```

If you want the input to exactly match the order in the array then you need to check if the first character in the array matches the input and then remove it from the array :

```
    private function onInput(e:TextEvent):void 
    {
        if (!myarray.length || myarray[0] != e.text) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            myarray.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While your question is fairly cryptic, I'll try to answer it as best as possible.

`TextField` has a built-in [`restrict`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8d7bb3e8da6fb92f-20050207122bd5f80cb-7ff6.html) property which restricts the allowable input.

This means you can do something like `textField.restrict = "helo";` and the user will ONLY be allowed to enter the letters h, e, l, and o.

This does not address the fact that it appears you want the user to *only* enter the word 'hello.' For that, you will have to capture the user input as it comes in and prevent any unwanted characters:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.events.TextEvent;

var restrictionArray:Array = "hello".split("");
var currentLetterIndex:int = 0;
var restrictedTextField:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(restrictedTextField);
restrictedTextField.restrict = "helo";

restrictedTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT
restrictedTextField.width = 100;
restrictedTextField.height = 30;
restrictedTextField.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onKey);
function onKey(e:TextEvent):void {
    if(currentLetterIndex < restrictionArray.length && e.text == restrictionArray[currentLetterIndex])
    {
        currentLetterIndex++;
    }
    else
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

The above code keeps track of which letter is supposed to come next by way of the `restrictionArray` and the `currentLetterIndex`. Any letter that doesn't match is not typed into the `TextField` by using the `preventDefault` method.